# Mean and Variance in a normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, gaussian

I am trying to find the mean and variance for the following case.

$\beta = h+\alpha g f$

What will be the mean, variance of $\beta$ if $h,g,f $ all are distributed as $x \sim \mathcal{C}{N}(0,\sigma_{x}^2)$, $x \in [h,g,f]$. Also, let us assume that $\sigma^2_x = 2$ and $\alpha$ is some constant.

Comment: Are $h,g,f$ independent?

Comment: Yes....$h,g,f$ are i.i.d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't even need the normality here.

$E(\beta) = E(h) + \alpha E(g)E(f) = 0.$

$Var(\beta) = E(\beta^2) = E(h^2 + 2 \alpha h g f + \alpha^2 g^2 f^2) = Var(h) + \alpha^2 Var(g) Var(f) = 2 + 4\alpha^2$.

Comment: Ok... i understood your answer related to mean of $\beta$. Can you please tell whether my understanding related to variance of $\beta$ obtained by you is correct ? $Var(\beta) = E(h^2)+2\alpha E(h) E(g) E(f) + \alpha^2 E(g^2) E(f^2)$ = $Var(h) + 2\cdot \alpha \cdot 0 \cdot 0 \cdot 0 + \alpha^2 Var(g) Var(f)$ = $2+0+\alpha^2 2\cdot 2$ =  $2+\alpha^2 4$

Comment: @ shang, Also what is meant by your comment "We don't even need the normality here"

Comment: Yes. You are on target.  The result holds even if $h, g, f$ are NOT normally distributed. We just need them to have mean of 0, variance of 2, and joint independence.

Comment: Ok.... Thanks for your efforts and comments...